# How to retain form values with Zend paginator

Tags: zend-framework, pagination

I have a page that has a form on top for selecting filters. When submitted, this form data is used in combination with Zend paginator to display results. But when I use paginator to page through the results, the form fields are lost as paginator does not post the form. Is there a simple way to combine these? I have had a difficult time searching for this as it is difficult to explain.

my controller is of this form...

```
    $form = new Application_Form_Myform();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $data = $request->getPost();
        $form->populate($data);

        // get the data
        Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial('pagination.phtml');
        $reportsTBL = new Model_DBTable_Reports();
        $paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Array($reportsTBL->getLog($data)));
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page',1))
              ->setItemCountPerPage(50);
        $this->view->paginator = $paginator
    } 
    $this->view->form = $form;
```

As you can see, this gets the values from the form and retains them for first submit. But on subsequent pagination clicks, they get lost. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So simple, Use [Zend Session](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.html) to keep your filters .

Something like this

```
$sessionNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Searchs');
$sessionNamespace->filter = $this->_request->getParam('filter');
if(isset($sessionNamespace->filter )) {
// do your stuff
}
```

Comment: and If user do filter, go to another page and come back to that page with filter? Filter form should be empty...

Comment: all this can be handled by checking the page no.

Comment: ... better is to check if request goes from page with filter (controller/action)

Comment: it's not a good option to use Session for this because it won't allow having multiple search windows (filters would be global to the session) and it's totally not seo friendly

Comment: @JoaquínL.Robles For multiple search windows you can use multiple indexes in zend session namespace. It works properly. I cannot understand the reason for downvote

Comment: @AwaisQarni using Session for search isn't seo friendly and won't allow the user to save the search as a "Favourite", for instance..

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you have to pass that form's data again, 
so you can do it throw GET(you can use session but that is a harder way).

My way in that situation is to append that key/value form's data from last submit 
to pagination URL,
so when someone click on next page, in the URL(GET) will be form's data

I get that form's data, in controller:

```
//it doesn't matter whether the POST or GET.
$this->_getParam('form_field_name');
```

If you want to create that URL for pagination in some pagination.phtml partial:

```
$urlParams = array();
foreach (Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParams() as $urlParamsKey=>$urlParamsVal){
    if (!in_array($urlParamsKey, array('module', 'controller', 'action', 'page'))){
        $urlParams[$urlParamsKey] = $urlParamsVal;
    }
}

// ...

//and than just make URL with URL helper
$this->url(array_merge(array('page' => 1), $urlParams)));
```

Comment: I had thought of this but I always find it messy to have complex urls that expose variables to the user, thus inviting the opportunity for hack attempts. Session variables are actually more secure, but a bit more of a hassle.